# Exclude a jqGrid Column From onSelect Functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, free-jqgrid

In my jqGrid(4.13.3 - free) when I click on a row the onSelect fires as desired. But I would like to be able to click in certain columns and the onSelect not be fired. Is this possible?

If I click on an icon the twenty-fourth column I do not want the following code to fire.

```
onSelectRow: oSelect

function oSelect(id){

        var p = $("#planningmatrixlist").jqGrid("getGridParam");
        var colModel = $("#planningmatrixlist").jqGrid("getGridParam", "colModel");
        var cm = p.colModel[p.iColByName.seatassy];
        delete cm.editoptions.dataEvents;

        selID = id;
        temp = $("#planningmatrixlist").getRowData(id)['editflag'];
        cr = $("#planningmatrixlist").getRowData(id)['componentroot'];
        wu = $("#planningmatrixlist").getRowData(id)['whereused'];
        tc = $("#planningmatrixlist").getRowData(id)['config'];
        $("#planningmatrixlist").setColProp('seatassy', { editoptions: { dataUrl: '/QMSWebApp/AssyComponentListSupportControllerServlet?lifecycle=seatassyoptionlist'}, defaultValue: 0});
        $("#planningmatrixlist").setColProp('back', { editoptions: {dataEvents: [{ type: 'focus', fn: function(e) {componentconfig(this.name,this.value);  }}]}});
        $("#planningmatrixlist").setColProp('bottom', { editoptions: {dataEvents: [{ type: 'focus', fn: function(e) {componentconfig(this.name,this.value);  }}]}});
        $("#planningmatrixlist").setColProp('legrest', { editoptions: {dataEvents: [{ type: 'focus', fn: function(e) {componentconfig(this.name,this.value);  }}]}});
        $("#planningmatrixlist").setColProp('headrest', { editoptions: {dataEvents: [{ type: 'focus', fn: function(e) {componentconfig(this.name,this.value);  }}]}});
        $("#planningmatrixlist").setColProp('lit', { editoptions: {dataEvents: [{ type: 'focus', fn: function(e) {componentconfig(this.name,this.value);  }}]}});
        $("#planningmatrixlist").setColProp('iprintstatus', { editoptions: { dataUrl: '/QMSWebApp/AssyComponentListSupportControllerServlet?lifecycle=yesnooptionlist'}, defaultValue: 0});
        $("#planningmatrixlist").setColProp('copyfrom', { editoptions: { dataUrl: '/QMSWebApp/AssyComponentListSupportControllerServlet?lifecycle=copyfromoptionlist'}, defaultValue: 0});
        $("#planningmatrixlist").setColProp('copyfrom', { editoptions: {dataEvents: [{ type: 'change', fn: function(e) {if($(this).val() !=0){copyfrom(this.value);}  }}]}});
        $("#planningmatrixlist").setColProp('arm', { editoptions: {dataEvents: [{ type: 'focus', fn: function(e) {componentconfig(this.name,this.value);  }}]}});
        $("#planningmatrixlist").setColProp('placard', { editoptions: {dataEvents: [{ type: 'focus', fn: function(e) {componentconfig(this.name,this.value);  }}]}});
        $("#planningmatrixlist").setColProp('baseframe', { editoptions: {dataEvents: [{ type: 'focus', fn: function(e) {componentconfig(this.name,this.value);  }}]}});
        $("#planningmatrixlist").setColProp('underseatshroud', { editoptions: {dataEvents: [{ type: 'focus', fn: function(e) {componentconfig(this.name,this.value);  }}]}});



        if(temp == 1){

            alert("This item can only be edited from " + cr + ".\r\nAdd a new configuration of this item to change components.");
            $("#edit_" + myGridId).addClass('ui-state-disabled');

        }
        else{

            $("#edit_" + myGridId).removeClass('ui-state-disabled');

        }
        //alert(tc);        
    };
```

Comment: Sorry, but I can't follows you. First of all what you mean under `onSelect`? Is it `onSelectRow` or `onCellSelect`? You wrote: "I would like to be able to click in certain columns and the onSelect not be fired." I don't understand what you mean. Do you want **to prevent selection** of row if the user click on the cell of some specific column of the row?

Comment: Sorry, yes onSelectRow. I have several columns in the row. The last column contains icons that when clicked drive other functions. When the row is selected I check for certain criteria and based on that an alert message may appear if the row is not editable. I would like this functionality to be skipped if an icon in the last column is clicked.

Comment: I'm still not sure that I understand your correctly. You wrote "I would like this functionality to be skipped". Do you want to prevent selection of the row in the specific case (the click on an icon in the last column) or you want to *detect* that the click was on the that column or on the icon? The 3-d parameter of the `onSelectRow` callback is event object (for example, `e`), which provide all required details (`e.target` is the clicked element `$(e.target).closest("tr.jqgrow>td")[0].cellIndex` is `iCol`). It would be much better, if you post the code fragment what demonstrates the problem.

Comment: First thanks for taking time to help me with this. I have updated post to show code I need to keep from firing.

Comment: Sorry, but the code don't explain what you need to implement. If you post some code then you should remove all unneeded details. Who have an interest about 13 changes of column properties? If the call of `setColProp` is important for understanding of your problem, than it's enough to include one from the 13 calls. Much more important are other things: **which editing mode you use? which `datatype` you use? do you use local data (including `loadonce:true`)? You wrote "I would like to be able to click in *certain columns* and the onSelect not be fired". Which column you mean on your example?**

Comment: @Oleg your comment on the 24th about the 3-d parameter guided me to what I needed to make this work(! target.is( "img" ). Thank you for all your help. I will remember next time to be more conservative with my code example and more descriptive with my issue.

Comment: You are welcome! I'll write later short answer with the information. Other developers could have close problems